# WPF can't locate a class even if in the same namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following Code behind of a XAML page:

```
namespace Paone
{
public partial class Controls : Page
{
    public Controls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Uri Website { get; set; }
        public bool IsBillionaire { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Paone.Controls"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Paone" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Controls">   
...

 <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="genderEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type Type="local:Gender" />
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- The columns: -->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Website" Binding="{Binding Website}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Billionaire?" Binding="{Binding IsBillionaire}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Gender" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Gender}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource genderEnum}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- The data: -->
        <local:Record FirstName="Adam" LastName="Nathan" Website="http://twitter.com/adamnathan" Gender="Male"/>
        <local:Record FirstName="Bill" LastName="Gates" Website="http://twitter.com/billgates" IsBillionaire="True" Gender="Male"/>
    </DataGrid>
```

As far as I can see, both pieces of code, the code behind page and the XAML deal with the "Paone" namespace.
However in the lines:

```
<x:Type Type="local:Gender" />
```

As well as:

```
<local:Record FirstName="Adam" LastName="Nathan" Website="http://twitter.com/adamnathan" Gender="Male"/>
<local:Record FirstName="Bill" LastName="Gates" Website="http://twitter.com/billgates" IsBillionaire="True" Gender="Male"/>
```

The Enum Gender and the class Record are not recognized by the system...

Why is that?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score -2):

The enum is inside the class Controls. Try Controls.Gender

Comment: Alternatively you could place the enum and Record class outside of the Controls class.

Comment: I tried both options before posting... Doesn't work...